# starting container process caused: error loading seccomp filter into kernel: loading seccomp filter: errno 524: unknown

Tags: kernel, docker

The container I am trying to start fails with the error below:

```
root@node652 ~ # docker start worker-bfb9e442-de92-4f94-9811-68aa14351983-1
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime cr


----------


eate failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: error loading seccomp filter into the kernel: loading seccomp filter: errno 524: unknown
```

Host Machine Info:

- OS: Linux Ubuntu 20.04
- Kernel: 5.13.0-52-generic

Container Info:

- OS: Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Below is the result from inspecting the container:

```
root@node652 ~ # docker inspect worker-bfb9e442-de92-4f94-9811-68aa14351983-1
[
    {
        "Id": "f66f6b1951328155f11cc0a6dd28a1c5ad4a946cee2a4d611f94b5e99b3157ed",
        "Created": "2022-11-02T03:55:43.508356534Z",
        "Path": "/usr/bin/start.sh",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "created",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 128,
            "Error": "OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: error loading seccomp filter into the kernel: loading seccomp filter: errno 524: unknown",
            "StartedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:c5e39732c153ddc0c480f8db72120aed494d258f86fb52ddce544982ebda8a7e",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f66f6b1951328155f11cc0a6dd28a1c5ad4a946cee2a4d611f94b5e99b3157ed/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f66f6b1951328155f11cc0a6dd28a1c5ad4a946cee2a4d611f94b5e99b3157ed/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f66f6b1951328155f11cc0a6dd28a1c5ad4a946cee2a4d611f94b5e99b3157ed/hosts",
        "LogPath": "",
        "Name": "/worker-bfb9e442-de92-4f94-9811-68aa14351983-1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/var/x/robots:/var/x/robots:rw",
                "/etc/x/worker-config.json:/etc/x/config.json:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "journald",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "host",
            "PortBindings": null,
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 800,
            "Memory": 6442450944,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 12884901888,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9a3cb65080a965e3c95381ff7066b3eca775dd87efdca18b3bb36872b90454e3-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e7ef55114f82776619eb39fd435f86e7117666d2540942393d03c005a4096cac/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bdaab58136b9461d07a2defee8999139eba35b6c513b48bb163f6169222e54e9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1fcc40a58769204a2b9df20d06bb7a2aca82e2171ad28c2f1558145eba2b76b7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d57d3c7be7552fb934be274fa9e176f203eeb62a971259db3fcfd14baa2d4284/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f259db67a53dc701e8e9573e7095d00b2207b988e1696cfe4a29c5f7f672d585/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3fe168bff518028075ec679dc8fe2fe5baa6094bfa7c86c4e3303c8b330f8b2d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0d9bf2552705944b8877a8a0d1fa3ab86c515e659544580750c304c40d08005c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e2c6c66d6c604181cacf3298a78b05c5eab657abf12296dd2f8881830096a50e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/265f68a27b23e222ea9468e436d39280799e4084e40db4017be6148ac0d32593/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4de0d69103b8c2c653a00e8caa00474d6234dafa8fc0465409e3d4fa99adc7bb/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5860027f5ab80369a08f3eb48205b90023f340f7b2e1270fec3e0118d5c14b7f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cafb6d5bd165de7e4ec189b9b11e0526197be3099b49b0c398b3bf1151e519e0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/262f356a30bd36c8525bdec4696a5dabbdd127a837372370fb11b612b489f91a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c986c6b16f6d1a60cf7e01164a5a95d2c03ee8d29a343cf6b0c2affaa80b98b2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/53635808a99e7301c52a41c75df0f040f72879a8f7a65be55ec5643b5bf4dd8b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4d972faec22bb4b9229b4cb35876f668788e85913d0bef3c66ed473475793581/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/eaf6f6b20addd5b4df1c805af2078f1ebb7da0b96d996b6969fa4dd4dfac06ef/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ad904f6965b2a9f693ae139df63ea0452aab734a8c800f2ee63dce0f4f5603f6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b6301269a74ee68739be5c1c0a666bb78517f4942094ae1b9311320e2cdb8c23/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3709fab76fad2a4649a93db9f4f1076b313d6ecc74f20f8ba41ebb7e45a5bab2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/97fa5baf46ef6c5900d750e667cec939338f293fa3c972aa2fb8b2db70e4f33a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1ff06fa8f11516a0e496708ff999b9ece4e40e17405d01a631310aabe66b600e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8df95a19a0b36dfa66c29e2312f1f536a8ed522d6db9cae908c3eff5250465e4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/791a92b8520580cbd0a25bdb8211322d59beeceaf8fe2d2381d7cf6ee2ada4ea/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a77eddf10c03caf38c793fcc37da8de58b4a3f9e04ca871f7915aad752703397/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/287a95eda64787db2537de2f8e02c9f9be92fc3af658be5a7b783561dfcda19b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3b8d8c82690a1275ffd674b4e7d6fc4544d115f3b6895bb91f043762aef9bfbc/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/00428229ca9aa916c22cebb26b45c4a90b98ea6c330062c4138d6b21b0964c37/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/276b557517799dfa36393aa32fc8f56a6d4a04da7d1901cdf1dac9a0ff63a026/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1c81e46a727793e0ae112fedab2a8b05b5ba2aad9b55e412442f7db18364f6f3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/81bef9bc3d72527e8ea03c1e2c6820edb795798b636abfc62c9349ae29d977d5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bda30fb84fa86d573919e2f8d9ffcc154744add01449b6c1474b0b3c967ae266/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/32deed49edb781b2a0e4fe439b4811e41c215a321d0226d9fa525e742c1e240d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/da88ac8c1330bbe81d425f7c5c3c582b0c35dae13b13144d811e3280c9b5a238/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dcf79e806ae7a68793cc52471313d5ef8856e62b06c4707056a1dc61e05a5675/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e0eba585acfc40c7b8d73d9e9c50e8eb1f50206ca15ae41cb7fac9abb7d4ec0d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/75be81ae603ac936a8243de875a69c7999ac8c514ecee1f3ccbc6ce9824dc95a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/48894659391fc28420cbb98273a5c92bea4d5cb67a1762f8e0c2eb35b4599606/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/02865e54bc977ced13de1d1ab94eb26ba69544034819c692df08d87ee40364bf/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/26c1e65dbc3fbebd95e173b4706ad5ea73c0e67603cb42c361d57d0f8869233e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b5abdbcdcd11efcbe2dc89bbf968ed44b2601563ba9404d30e060c05b8ab958c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1c23f37d243b2229bef881957282acf7815975ec5b084d90d307b6b2537763dc/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8d73249df459625833352e4bfcf2f4572682d35ea78196067db7a2281afb132e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1fbb733820f55ee9937a7d7d7203b88b4c08d9eb943d642b1495dffad7932bcb/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e0d15ed5b3e23d9fc581d0ba87d5a7463f09a52ae4234c7ccfcb9658635be6b4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a63dba1ac69b843cafa2d863b972836e58ccbfe180da268841d5d1ee49c4c350/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7eac4bffc3a464dacc167f6bb39eaf6baf5403848bf91932eea86ebbce72074b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/499d010b34bf581bbdd4a54a861b45be837bd3b17952f10e4539e36ef1a2b2db/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a3e59b9d2d484798edd53b8584db74b0c2034125fa9eed582d090eb0bdc772cb/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e7439d7260ae9cda648b9ee9d4c2fe7ea20894c58e355775ff95bdee5ba1aaeb/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/55b01bd28a7a246a619e7eb505eae5aaf66fda4f725adcc3bd1fcd99e79b0cba/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/13d8d8d305513868369b3d19da7eab672e18c40515068c207325ca42b228473f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6323e33721daf42631175e5f70b57806cee00f08b974138f23717840a28639c7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a8a8573be23b9f6ba95f177cd39b26ff7e6c8c07943b39499f7cc37d88c8330c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/74fa132a0cfdb91474e6d000ebf3883a153ab8095dfc016c5d1a7543e5ecbb95/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ba665cb763f824204b7edaaaaff9b4df43d3020b555cb23b6b9d0d8dbfec2922/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9dbb340402b9abc04421ffcc511bb3c56f5f46986508c981f976db973a2c7f82/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4977eff33c0f46be87f76c7ca0a4eda856b200a8d2d6d7cc101161a750290e3b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/998ec0162327eaba47bc70e5ecc8400ebdf62d1e423b9e7836e27429301bc5e0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/03de6cc09a8739d1ef40c12759acb0ec59492755fecf8c9b64a473039cfbf1da/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7c228833baa9a9530df08413456c3f8e7a492a32dac8a9822a9079c6f66091de/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3431820b1a8bc049c6fdaf7ff5689f92fdec5a1187ce3158e02069149550df21/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a8a2743a1e58690b5b2d775e1bb229521b13f132028e4a8b422cf55d7fdd020a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fdb5e161046b4e3a895aa3bff8b68fd89fcae98bbee99431e1fd362744448f06/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/034375c186a430398e0a0f46f61b3fc94feffd8fc45f51a0f9f237c977358a8c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7f07ec8077333e7ff7b437bee3ca2f7dc3f2f134900bbb0a7fbe7e2e8110d6c3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/67ab7a56d92b6577071ea7a72948a4f0934ed5ebecce71b6cc1077fbb05ea44e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9f4a3e80ca27432ce9643b409a77a0776ad33b53aa13a5ef615fa43a85149f3c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4274b22c5905eedd4162dfaf36b534f201fc80b977aa299481b5094c715b8ade/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/eb4b141186d8b156059aee81c5e172a24b539cefaa8cf5b34ff51a7c6e5fc8a2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f2868053d7e670aca59fe112864163e56af3e5ec9a951d878d9125c4df7480cd/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9a3cb65080a965e3c95381ff7066b3eca775dd87efdca18b3bb36872b90454e3/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9a3cb65080a965e3c95381ff7066b3eca775dd87efdca18b3bb36872b90454e3/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9a3cb65080a965e3c95381ff7066b3eca775dd87efdca18b3bb36872b90454e3/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/var/x/robots",
                "Destination": "/var/x/robots",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/etc/x/worker-config.json",
                "Destination": "/etc/x/config.json",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "node652.production.x.io",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "root:root",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": true,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NPM_TOKEN=095f4c61-35cf-410f-beab-968bcc2f063e",
                "BROWSER_ENGINE=chrome"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/usr/bin/start.sh"
            ],
            "Image": "x/scraper-worker-chrome:production",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/node/scraper",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "x-bot": "",
                "resultId": "bfb9e442-de92-4f94-9811-68aa14351983",
                "robotType": "SCRAPER"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "c812a59e3899311037c7000062f5f58ced39e38c23d573613f8d9bb75266ec85",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "9cb1448d940d2d1d7986ab75d2e2326bb5107b5ec404c79f93ae5603e70f2787",
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I have tried to:

- reboot the machine
- upgrade the kernel of the host machine to the latest kernel

and nothing worked. I am lost here because the error is not helpful and searching on the web didn't have any information to help me understand this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards,
Rando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by adding the --security-opt="seccomp=unconfined" when running the container. E.g:

```
docker run --rm -it --security-opt="seccomp=unconfined" image-name
```